# How to implement a continuous producer-consumer pattern inside a Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, windows-services, tpl-dataflow

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- Keep a queue in memory of items that need processed (i.e. `IsProcessed = 0`)
- Every 5 seconds, get unprocessed items from the db, and if they're not already in the queue, add them
- Continuous pull items from the queue, process them, and each time an item is processed, update it in the db (`IsProcessed = 1`)
- Do this all "as parallel as possible"

I have a constructor for my service like

```
public MyService()
{
    Ticker.Elapsed += FillQueue;
}
```

and I start that timer when the service starts like

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Ticker.Enabled = true;
    Task.Run(() => { ConsumeWork(); });
}
```

and my `FillQueue` is like

```
private static async void FillQueue(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)   
{
    var items = GetUnprocessedItemsFromDb();
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        if(!Work.Contains(item))
        {
            Work.Enqueue(item);
        }   
    }
}
```

and my `ConsumeWork` is like

```
private static void ConsumeWork()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(Work.Count > 0)
        {
            var item = Work.Peek();
            Process(item);
            Work.Dequeue();
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

However this is probably a naive implementation and I'm wondering whether .NET has any type of class that is exactly what I need for this type of situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though @JSteward' answer is a good start, you can improve it with [mixing up](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2013/01/31/mixing-tpl-dataflow-with-reactive-extensions/) the `TPL-Dataflow` and [`Rx.NET` extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/), as a dataflow block may easily become an observer for your data, and with [`Rx` Timer](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/develop/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable.Time.cs) it will be much less effort for you ([`Rx.Timer` explanation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timer.html)).

We can adjust [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242977.aspx) for your needs, like this:

```
private const int EventIntervalInSeconds = 5;
private const int DueIntervalInSeconds = 60;

var source =
    // sequence of Int64 numbers, starting from 0
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229435.aspx
    Observable.Timer(
        // fire first event after 1 minute waiting
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DueIntervalInSeconds),
        // fire all next events each 5 seconds
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(EventIntervalInSeconds))
    // each number will have a timestamp
    .Timestamp()
    // each time we select some items to process
    .SelectMany(GetItemsFromDB)
    // filter already added
    .Where(i => !_processedItemIds.Contains(i.Id));

var action = new ActionBlock<Item>(ProcessItem, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        // we can start as many item processing as processor count
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount,
    });

IDisposable subscription = source.Subscribe(action.AsObserver());
```

Also, your check for item being already processed isn't quite accurate, as there is a possibility to item get selected as unprocessed from db right at the time you've finished it's processing, yet didn't update it in database. In this case item will be removed from `Queue<T>`, and after that added there again by producer, this is why I've added the [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) to this solution (`HashSet<T>` isn't thread-safe):

```
private static async Task ProcessItem(Item item)
{
    if (_processedItemIds.Contains(item.Id))
    {
        return;
    }

    _processedItemIds.Add(item.Id);
    // actual work here

    // save item as processed in database

    // we need to wait to ensure item not to appear in queue again 
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(EventIntervalInSeconds * 2));

    // clear the processed cache to reduce memory usage
    _processedItemIds.Remove(item.Id);
}

public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

// temporary cache for items in process
private static ConcurrentBag<Guid> _processedItemIds = new ConcurrentBag<Guid>();

private static IEnumerable<Item> GetItemsFromDB(Timestamped<long> time)
{
    // log event timing
    Console.WriteLine($"Event # {time.Value} at {time.Timestamp}");

    // return items from DB
    return new[] { new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid() } };
}
```

You can implement cache clean up in other way, for example, start a "GC" timer, which will remove processed items from cache on regular basis.

To stop events and processing items you should `Dispose` the subscription and, maybe, `Complete` the `ActionBlock`:

```
subscription.Dispose();
action.Complete();
```

You can find more information about `Rx.Net` in their [guidelines on github](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/develop/Rx.NET/Documentation/Rx%20Design%20Guidelines.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `ActionBlock` to do your processing, it has a built in queue that you can post work to. You can read up on tpl-dataflow here: [Intro to TPL-Dataflow](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14782) also [Introduction to Dataflow, Part 1](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/09/introduction-to-dataflow-part-1.html). Finally, this is a quick sample to get you going. I've left out a lot but it should at least get you started.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace MyWorkProcessor {

    public class WorkProcessor {

        public WorkProcessor() {
            Processor = CreatePipeline();
        }    

        public async Task StartProcessing() {
            try {
                await Task.Run(() => GetWorkFromDatabase());
            } catch (OperationCanceledException) {
                //handle cancel
            }
        }

        private CancellationTokenSource cts {
            get;
            set;
        }

        private ITargetBlock<WorkItem> Processor {
            get;
        }

        private TimeSpan DatabasePollingFrequency {
            get;
        } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

        private ITargetBlock<WorkItem> CreatePipeline() {
            var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() {
                BoundedCapacity = 100,
                CancellationToken = cts.Token
            };
            return new ActionBlock<WorkItem>(item => ProcessWork(item), options);
        }

        private async Task GetWorkFromDatabase() {
            while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested) {
                var work = await GetWork();
                await Processor.SendAsync(work);
                await Task.Delay(DatabasePollingFrequency);
            }
        }

        private async Task<WorkItem> GetWork() {
            return await Context.GetWork();
        }

        private void ProcessWork(WorkItem item) {
            //do processing
        }
    }
}
```